# Custom legend colors in Vega-Lite chart

Tags: vega-lite

When I have more than one line layer on my chart, the line colors in the legend do not match the line color in the chart itself.

I want to have the legend color match the line color, ie, if the line in the chart is red, I want the matching legend color to be red as well.

On our charts the legend information for the dataset data is added in via:
`encoding.strokeWidth.datum`

Which appears to work ok with a single dataset line, but when there are multiple dataset lines the legend colors don't match up with the line colors in the chart.

Being new to vega-lite, this seems like a side-effect to me, and not the correct way of addressing this.

Here is a Vega editor share showing a representative example.
[example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUADJQBWENgDsQAGhCY6guGhAqQAdxoATetqiLMSGgrgAnXWYUAzGmTSgoDCJjYIAYmxtkTAAVAE8cOAg0TBsGOFUkAA8aKNRQQSQmOEF-BUxtACU2JjZvXQysnPMAZRoALy1UAEYAJlUK7NzMAHU4Fyw0ABZJSXbM7IBhNkEA7UlEsUcANgBmJYAOEABfdvI4BUM3EAhQhBLBAHkcJCg6ULQm1QCaffz0EuwfXUMaGzgodSKbQwZ51cxIQT2aYMBAKVKDLY7ECGJAWCBwTCpUAotEYgD6RjxTTQAG1QMQIXEHm1kajGiAWpIWi1+JImvwmpJgk1BqgRnzpCNJAAtbbKcmUxrM1Q4+mM5mslmc7m8-kjKQjUU7CWCKmoJZLGV07TylmSFYcrk8gUCjUisU6vUrFZGzByplmwaWlU29VCrUAXVdSHRmAJhjxLVJjqlNNlJo9rPZyutasFmodIApusarVd7oVTO9qcktv9mezeoAnIbaW6E4WLSnVaW-RntVnJWhnfmG57iy2y+2A0iMqFbNG6yg0p2c6kySBkIkHiNVAgrGhGaoyDY2AwcNpvAetiO10gbABrI6YcL0v4AqEzOzoADETTg6zgKy0T2utxvaCCusSL7GYPwKK4M73DOSBkDufD1ugS66M42SHEhSRiiAoRRjBcF-BQiGLhuqioYI6HEUoSJmE+RxkRRO57geqjqJgmjaLoN4RNoCg+FYEK6NAEKNNiPiWEoqAkiAHzeAgnFsAeQYgDYSAQY0UkvoYVYrEyYi6G+H5flop4gJoZD7OhoAnGc0xhNx6AQAAjgw54-scpznFcNx3IBlAtIiv7eQBM6Vo0QGIh2OLTjG86gMhqBbpRgHbru+7aDJXwnkiyCXtet7aPe+SqDRsyvlpOktHpgX-tB4WqKBbDgZBoDQaAsHwYR9LIaRLzkdoyFIjhRztQRxpISRID0f1G7UdMpWgFN6CMWlLEaPSnH5egvHrgoAmqEJ7EzoYYkbpJ0mlLJ8mKaoKlqaSICadpun6e+n7fiAJlmRZRzWecdn0k5Ll-IJHnTF5NW+f5SIKUFrWznq4UBdiqLRSAu0IPSUWhuGRJYTlV4zlx9LCNYj6lQ9TRIAA7N+mz7TEbAXnA3RGCYCUgQoYFWM12F0b1FGhRt9kgM5qmsaiNCkLoSQpNea3aAAkpzRivFEAUgMuhM0BjACqCh0No47ngg5gwPGPVodo5tqPL6DS8kWKmeMOS6hAMDRLE8Q21AF5TAweRoGI6teLuTMs8Y7tHaiMLaAAEtMoQAASx6phjwbthiRNsSNTkc6OYyj2OElG2XngToBE9oJNuSVz7KXAhz06HzOs5H-n1ZzjXc0ccOLfDbmV+got5HQEtSwkDty2x9JK7cmd5GrSKaxX2twHrBvoEbgSm9bffW6xh06BPsszh0LueJHMRxKtPt+wHqBB0iIeMy3EdHDiMfoAAagE1yCInBRMhMDoIvLKQA)

Comment: The link doesn't work Greg. Please update. Can you also clarify your expected results.

Comment: Sorry about that, link updated (and verified).

I also clarified what I am looking for in a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.0.json",
  "title": "",
  "width": "container",
  "config": {
    "customFormatTypes": true,
    "axis": {
      "labelFont": "Roboto",
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelFontWeight": 400,
      "labelColor": "0x5f6368"
    },
    "legend": {
      "symbolOpacity": 1,
      "orient": "bottom",
      "direction": "horizontal",
      "columns": 4
    }
  },
  "datasets": {
    "dataset_id_1": [
      {"value": 12, "date": "2022-01-10T14:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": 22, "date": "2022-02-10T14:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": 66, "date": "2022-03-10T14:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": 33, "date": "2022-04-10T14:00:00.000Z"}
    ],
    "dataset_id_2": [
      {"value": 22, "date": "2022-01-10T14:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": 12, "date": "2022-02-10T14:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": 96, "date": "2022-03-10T14:00:00.000Z"},
      {"value": 33, "date": "2022-04-10T14:00:00.000Z"}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {"values": [{"max": 100, "min": 20, "group": "top"}]},
      "mark": {"type": "rect", "color": "#1e8e3e", "opacity": 0.08},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "max"},
        "y2": {"aggregate": "min", "field": "min"},
        "fill": {
          "field": "group",
          "title": "",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {
            "domain": ["bottom", "top"],
            "range": ["#d93025", "#1e8e3e"]
          },
          "legend": {"symbolType": "square", "symbolOpacity": 0.2}
        },
        "opacity": {"value": 0.08}
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {"values": [{"max": 20, "min": 0, "group": "bottom"}]},
      "mark": {"type": "rect", "color": "#d93025", "opacity": 0.08},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "max"},
        "y2": {"aggregate": "min", "field": "min"},
        "fill": {
          "field": "group",
          "title": "",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {
            "domain": ["bottom", "top"],
            "range": ["#d93025", "#1e8e3e"]
          },
          "legend": {"symbolType": "square", "symbolOpacity": 0.2}
        },
        "opacity": {"value": 0.08}
      }
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "data": {"name": "dataset_id_1"},
          "transform": [{"calculate": "'Holy Handgrenades'", "as": "c"}],
          "mark": {"type": "line", "strokeWidth": 2},
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "field": "value",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {"title": "Incidents"}
            },
            "x": {
              "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
              "field": "date",
              "title": "",
              "axis": {"labelFlush": true, "tickCount": 5}
            },
            "stroke": {
              "scale": {"range": ["red", "blue"]},
              "field": "c",
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "data": {"name": "dataset_id_2"},
          "transform": [{"calculate": "'Vorpal Rabbits'", "as": "c"}],
          "mark": {"type": "line", "strokeWidth": 2},
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "field": "value",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {"title": "Incidents"}
            },
            "x": {
              "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
              "field": "date",
              "title": "",
              "axis": {"labelFlush": true, "tickCount": 5}
            },
            "stroke": {"field": "c"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi David (or anyone who might know), 
Is there anyway to either assign the order items appear in the legend (like if I want 'Vorpal Rabbits' to appear first), or assign a specific color from the color range to a specific line/layer (if I want 'Vorpal Rabbits' to always be rendered in RED)?

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi Greg - please post as a new question and myself or someone else will take a look.

Comment: posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76094653/how-to-set-legend-order-in-vega-lite-charts-bonus-for-being-able-to-set-assig